# Is there any way to disable usb ports(Not ethernet ) on Raspberry pi 3b+?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

I wrote a script for raspberry pi, I added my script to /etc/profile and my script saved in the pi home directory. My script is like a loop, It should not be interrupted using the keyboard or something. What is the best way to do this? Should I add some lines to stop someone from interrupting my script or disable USB ports(Not ethernet)?

I have tried "TRAP" but after pressing CTRL+C multiple times it is exiting from my script.

`trap ' ' 2 3 6 15 INT TSTP`

Comment: `trap` should work, you don't need to disable ports.

Comment: You could also use `stty` to disable the interrupt key.

Comment: @Barmar It's working for 2 or 3 keystrokes but the problem is when we hold CTRL+C at some point it's breaking and coming out of the script. I need to overcome that issue. Please help.

Comment: The `stty` solution should work.

Comment: Example using stty, please

Comment: @Barmar Is there any chance that I can encrypt my script? I don't anyone to see what's inside my script file. Need help

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90178/how-can-i-either-encrypt-or-render-my-shell-script-unreadable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stty` to enable and disable the interrupt keys.

```
stty -isig # disable interrupt keys
# ... code that needs protecting
stty isig # enable interrupt keys
```